# How do I get the output field as an array in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How do I get the output field as an array.

What I currently have:

```
db.users.find({ taskIds: { $in: [ObjectId("638764689c4ed1fbff18859a")] } }, {taskIds:1})
```

The output of it:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("638764689c4ed1fbff1885a2"),
    taskIds: [
      ObjectId("638764689c4ed1fbff18859a"),
      ObjectId("638764689c4ed1fbff18859c")
    ]
  }
]
```

The output I want:

```
[
  {
     ObjectId("638764689c4ed1fbff18859a"),
     ObjectId("638764689c4ed1fbff18859c")
  }
]
```

Comment: The output you want is not a valid BSON/JSON. An object should have key-value pair. I believe what you want is an array of ObjectId(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just to omit the `_id` from the result, you need to add it to your projection as follows:
`db.users.find({ taskIds: { $in: [ObjectId("638764689c4ed1fbff18859a")] } }, {taskIds:1, _id:-1})`

This would produce:

```
[
  {
    taskIds: [
      ObjectId("638764689c4ed1fbff18859a"),
      ObjectId("638764689c4ed1fbff18859c")
    ]
  }
]
```